# Google Sheets / Excel Array Formula for Creating Lists of Words that Appear Certain Number of Times

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm using Google Sheets but I'm not sure if I what I want to accomplish is possible in Sheets. If it is not, I can use Excel.

I have a large list of text listed in column A on Sheet2. Each cell in column A contains a single-word, unique text that we'll call characteristics.

On Sheet1 in column C, I have a list of accounts. Right now, I manually assign one of these characteristics to each account randomly by looking at the list in column A Sheet2, grabbing a characteristics and pasting it into Sheet1 column D, next to the respective account.

I have to re-use these characteristics because they are limited in quantity and I have a larger number of accounts. My goal is to re-use characteristics as little as possible, or to ensure that each characteristic is re-used an even number of times (so that one characteristic is not re-used 5x, while another is only re-used 2x).

I thought the best way to do this would be to create a formula that checked Sheet1 column D to see which characteristics have been used once and to then populate that list of words into a new column on Sheet2 column B - then to see which characteristics have been used twice and to populate that list of words into a new column on Sheet2 column C, and so on.

I have done some research trying to learn how this can be done, but I am a novice in these matters and it appears I may need to use an Array formula and the nature of this goal is too complex for me to learn in the period of time I have allotted for this task.

How can I accomplish this goal?

Bonus points: How can I incorporate a check into Sheet2 column A to also report a list of words that have NOT been used yet in Sheet1 column D?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's a sample data sheet to help illustrate. I used a list of colors from Wikipedia as my characteristics. Please let me know if there is anything else I can do or explain to help clarify. Thanks in advance for your response!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12IDfkz_qBlED_WLBHVwUvUL0DVqeGYe1i28gS_x6eUA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: very nice and wordy description of what you are doing it may be helpful to some to provide some sample data of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: can you please share a sample sheet

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your comments and feedback. I prepared a sample data sheet to help illustrate this. For characteristics, I used a list of colors from WIkipedia to help illustrate. Hopefully this adds clarity. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12IDfkz_qBlED_WLBHVwUvUL0DVqeGYe1i28gS_x6eUA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version of your google sheet: [Updated Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12IDfkz_qBlED_WLBHVwUvUL0DVqeGYe1i28gS_x6eUA/edit#gid=1627767373).

You can use the `countif()` function to determine the number of times a characteristic occurs on the account characteristics column.

Place the output of the `countif()` function in the column next to your characteristics. You can then use the filter function, to create filtered list
`=iferror(filter(characteristics_range,count_range=desired_count),"")`.

The filter function is an array function, so it only needs to be placed in the first row of each occurrences range.

To show unused words, just set the desired count to 0.

In the attached example, I created separate columns for the desired occurrences from 0 through 6, then added the filter into each column to show the results. If no results are found for a given number of occurrences, then `#N/A` will be shown, but you can remove it using the `iferror()` function and setting the value to "".